# Manipulating layout on a previous activity in Android

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, xamarin.android

- I have an application that has a list of buttons created dynamically in the code. When one of these buttons is clicked, a new activity containing a similar list of buttons is added on top of the stack.
- These lists of buttons each have a different view for portrait and landscape, so I am overriding OnConfigurationChanged to lay update the existing buttons because it is faster than letting the view recreate itself.
- When the second view changes orientation, even though the previous activity is in the background, it performs the changes to the buttons in its list.
- The second activity is also transparent and you can see the previous activity through it. Normally you won't see the first activity from the second activity, but the entire second activity is in a HorizontalScrollView and the user can slide the view off the screen which then finishes the activity and goes back to the first activity.
- The problem is that when there are hundreds of buttons on each activity and both activities are being updated on orientation change, things slow down considerably.

In all my cases, I have noticed that things go smoothly if only one activity is being updated on orientation change. Is there any way I can postpone the previous activities changes OnConfigurationChange or speed this up in general?

Comment: Are you sure your activity is not recreating ? Do you have `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` in  manifest.

Comment: **I am overriding OnConfigurationChanged to lay update the existing buttons because it is faster than letting the view recreate itself.** is it worth it?

Comment: If you are using `ListView` properly then it doesn't matter how many `View`s you have. `ListView` handles them very nicely. You don't need to worry about things being smooth and fast.